# SAS code for calculating IV

Tags: sas

I found some code from obseveupdate websit. They are used for IV calculation. When I run it code it goes through, but all IV and Woe are zeros. I changed another data set to try, also get zeros for all variables. Could you help me figure out why?

```
data inputdata;
length Region $ 20 age $ 20 Gender $ 20; 
infile datalines dsd dlm= ':' truncover;
input Region $ age $ Gender $ target ;
datalines;
Scotland:18-25:Male:1
Scotland:18-25:Female:0
Scotland:26-35:Male:0
Wales:26-35:Male:1
Wales:36-45:Female:0
Wales:26-35:Male:1
London:36-45:Male:1
London:26-35:Male:0
London:18-25:Unknown:1
London:36-45:Male:0
Northern Ireland:36-45:Female:0
Northern Ireland:26-35:Male:1
Northern Ireland:36-45:Male:0
Engand (Not London):45+:Female:0
Engand (Not London):18-25:Male:1
Engand (Not London):26-35:Female:0
Engand (Not London):45+:Female:0
Engand (Not London):36-45:Female:1
Engand (Not London):45+:Female:1
; 

data _tempdata;
set inputdata;;
n=_n_;
run;


proc sort data=_tempdata;
by target n;
run;



proc transpose data=_tempdata out = _tempdata;
by target n;
var _character_ _numeric_;
run; 


proc sort data=_tempdata out=_tempdata;
by _name_ target;
run; 


proc freq data=_tempdata;
by _name_ target;
tables col1 /out=_tempdata;
run; 

proc sort data=_tempdata;
by _name_ col1;
run;


proc transpose data=_tempdata out=_tempdata;
by _name_ col1;
id target;
var percent;
run; 

data IV_Table(keep=variable IV) WOE_Table(keep=variable attribute woe);
set _tempdata;
by _name_; 

rename col1=attribute _name_=variable;
_0=sum(_0,0)/100; *Convert to percent and convert null to zero;
_1=sum(_1,0)/100; *Convert to percent and convert null to zero; 

woe=log(_0/_1)*100;output WOE_Table;*Output WOE;

if _1 ne 0 and _0 ne 0 then do; 
raw=(_0-_1)*log(_0/_1); 
end;
else raw=0; 

IV+sum(raw,0);*Culmulativly add to IV, set null to zero;

if last._name_ then do; *only _tempdata the last final row;
output IV_table;
IV=0;
end; 

where upcase(_name_) ^='TARGET' and upcase(_name_) ^= 'N';run;


proc sort data=IV_table;by descending IV;run;
title1 "IV Listing";proc print data=IV_table;run;
proc sort data=woe_table;
by variable WOE;
run;

title1 "WOE Listing";
proc print data=WOE_Table;run;
```

Comment: I feel _0=sum(_0,0)/100; 
_1=sum(_1,0)/100; is not correct because all values of _0 and _1 because zero. That leads to 0 values for WOE and IV

Comment: I find the answer myself. In stead of using the original code to convert from number to percent. I use:  data test;
  set _tempdata;
  array vars[*] _numeric_;
  _0=vars[1]/100;
  _1=vars[2]/100;
  if _0 =. then _0=0; else _0=_0;
  if _1 =. then _1=0; else _1=_1;
run;
It works!

Comment: You might consider posting your solution as an answer. That way, future users looking for this can more easily find it and link to it. You can also accept it as correct after a while and get a bit of reputation for it.